# Updating a Lambda Function Iteratively

Tags: python, lambda

**Update #2: Read first before below!**

## -------------------------

(special thanks to everyone for putting up with me so far)

Let me try to make it simpler. If I know the algorithm to calculate a function f beforehand but *do not* know its end result how would I do this for a number of function evaluations without redoing the algorithm each time?

```
f = lambda x: x**2
for pt in x:
#-----------
    for i in range(len(some_list)):
        #evaluate algorithm
        if condition 1:
            f = f + 1
        elif condition 2:
            f = f + 2
        else:
            f = f + 3
#-----------
    f(pt)
```

i.e. Say I want to remove everything within the #----------- and do the following:

```
f = lambda x: x**2
for i in range(len(some_list)):
    #evaluate algorithm
    if condition 1:
        f = lambda x: f(x) + 1
    elif condition 2:
        f = lambda x: f(x) + 2
    else:
        f = lambda x: f(x) + 3

for pt in x:
    f(pt)
```

This couldn't in fact be done since you would be overwriting previous f lambda functions. Overall I'm trying to reduce the number of times I in fact refind f. I want to only find it once but evaluate it multiple times.
I could hack it to do something like this:

```
f = lambda x: x**2
temp = []
for i in range(len(some_list)):
    #evaluate algorithm
    if condition 1:
        temp.append(lambda x = f(x) + 1)
    elif condition 2:
        temp.append(lambda x = f(x) + 2)
    else:
        temp.append(lambda x = f(x) + 3)
new_f = lambda x: sum([func(x) for func in temp])

for pt in x:
    new_f(pt)
```

## -------------------------

I'm hoping someone here may have tried to do this before.

I want to generate a lambda function for a matrix however, I don't know the matrix a priori ; I build it over a loop iteration. The idea is that each element in the matrix depends on neighbouring atoms, in pseudocode:

```
Matrix = zeros((N,N))
for i in atoms:
    Matrix.update
```

Now comes the problem, I have a bunch of vectors, say x which has 3 columns and say M rows. I want to evaluate this matrix for each row in x. I could do the following:

```
for pt in x:
    Matrix = zeros((N,N))
    for i in atoms:
        Matrix.update(@x)
```

However, It would be more computationally efficient if I can simply generate a lambda function of the Matrix so that I don't have to rebuild my matrix every time. So like:

```
Matrix = zeros((N,N))
for i in atoms
    l_Matrix = lambda x: Matrix + l_Matrix
l_Matrix(x)
```

It seems this would be difficult to do with python. Unfortunately you can't add lambda functions recursively in python as it would delete the memory of the previous instance and thus resulting in a broken recursion.

*The only way I can think about getting around this is to **make a list** where I would append lambda function and then add them all together at the end, giving me my final matrix lambda function.* Does anyone know of a cleaner way?

Thank you!

Update: an example.

```
for pt in x:
    Matrix = zeros((N,N))
    for i in atoms:
        #a bunch of if statements to determine what I do to the matrix element
        Matrix[i,i] = exp(2*pi*1.0j*sum(pt)) #for example
```

Ideally, I don't want to have to generate my matrix each time I want to know the matrix at point x. I would prefer to find it once then evaluate it.

I've gotten lots of interest, I am basically working on tight binding hamiltonians for atoms - they help to determine the electronic structure of compounds or alloys. See for a simple but detailed example : http://cacs.usc.edu/education/phys516/04TB.pdf

Comment: To salve memory saving problem, Instead of a list use a Tuple-it may be useful -.Removing individual tuple elements is not possible unless you use the del statement to explicitly remove an entire tuple.

Comment: If I'm understanding you correctly, I don't want to remove elements, although it is a possibility. I could append an item then remove it but the memory would still be there *(I think?)*.... I guess I'm looking to see if there is a way to iterate more elegantly on a lambda function.

Comment: If I understand your problem correctly, have you thought about creating a custom operator ?

Comment: @JacquesGaudin I'm not entirely sure I know what you mean by a custom operator, could you post a reference?

Comment: see this link : http://www.python-course.eu/python3_magic_methods.php

Comment: Your matrix could be a class (or sub-class of an already existing class), you would override the addition operator and when the matrix is ready you  call a method to do your operation on x... Would this work in your case ?

Comment: I'm not sure if an operator would help in this case, now that I know what you are talking about, maybe you can explain in more detail what you propose to happen? I'll update my original post so you can get an idea of what an example might be.

Comment: how about of using numpy, I am unfamiliar with it myself, but as far as I know it is the library to work with matrix stuff

Comment: @Copperfield indeed it is, it will do matrix operations, and I do use it. But as far as I know there isn't some sort of magical way to iterate on a lambda function with it.

Comment: checking your code I found little sense in it and I don't understand your final purpose, in your final example you always reset everything and don't use your `pt`, why? can you elaborate more

Comment: Yeah sorry, I fixed the `pt` bit. I can elaborate for sure, I was trying to keep it simple, and thanks for the interest! It would certainly help if I can put an equation above...

Anyways, imagine that you know what algorithm you must apply to get your final matrix. This would be the if statements in my update above. If I know how to build the matrix using an algorithm but don't know the full result before hand, how can I prevent myself from rebuilding it each time I want to evaluate it at my `pt`? Does this make more sense?

Comment: That algorithm can be found in wikipedia or some other place? if so you can put the link

Answer (score 2):

**Edit 2**

so you start with

```
F0(x) = x^2 # or whatever you want
```

and you want to get Fn such that

```
Fn(x) = Fn-1(x) + kn
```

in this case is simple, for example if you want F3

```
F0(x) = x^2
F1(x) = F0(x) + k1
F2(x) = F1(x) + k2
F3(x) = F2(x) + k3
```

then

```
F3(x) = F2(x) + k3
      = (F1(x) + k2) + k3  
      = F1(x) + (k2 + k3) 
      = (F0(x) + k1) + (k2 + k3) 
      = F0(x) + (k1 + k2 + k3)
```

from here one can deduce that

```
Fn(x) = F0(x) + sum( ki )
```

in code that will be

```
k = 0
for i in range(len(some_list)):
    #evaluate algorithm
    if condition 1:
        k += 1
    elif condition 2:
        k += 2
    else:
        k += 3

func = lambda x: x**2 + k
```

Comment: That is correct. Now what I am wishing to do is to avoid going through the nested loops `len(x)` times. So doing what you did but I only want to do the inner loop once, for efficiency. I've posted a link of the full think I am trying to do if you are interested.

Comment: that is quantum physics? I am lost there... Anyway, check my edit, avoiding the inner loop is possible depending on where are placed the condition

Comment: I applaud you all for being so interested and helping me out. Yeah it is quantum but more close to condensed matter physics. I've update my post to make you guys aware of more info. I feel like you are still doing what I am doing, i.e. having an argument inside the loop that I want to replace with a lambda function.

Comment: checking your new edit, then is easy just find the patter in there and the definition of your function is as simple as finding a constant

Answer (score 2):

You can use a list of lists(or NumPy library) or the nested list. However, this is a sample code to implement the dynamic nested list (A matrix).

Let's M be the number of rows:

```
 M=3
 X=[]
 Matrix=(x, M)
 for i in range(M):
     X.append([int(z) for z in atoms().split()])
     for i in M: //adding column:
        i.append(z)
        if (Matrix.reverse()): // Whenever you get the last element of your desired list
          Matrix[0]
          break;
```

Comment: python has matries. see `numpy.linalg`

Answer (score 0):

Based on your example:

```
Matrix = zeros((N,N)) 
for pt in x:
    v = exp(2*pi*1.0j*sum(pt))  # because it does not use i
    for i in atoms:
        #a bunch more of potential if statements to determine Matrix
        Matrix[i,i] = v
```

Comment: You have the gist of what I am trying to do so I will hijack a comment here. If I know I have the same structure for my Matrix (excluding the pt), how do I prevent remaking the matrix each time rather than just evaluating it at `pt`.

Consider if I need to do a whole lot more effort to determine the Matrix, i.e. if statements and a bunch of algorithms and function calling.

Comment: Right, we can also move the array creation outside the loop as it does not depend on x.